# Is there a way to build efficient vba function that will take a range as its argument and return an array of unique values (freed from duplicates)?

Tags: arrays, vba, function

I'd like to create vba function (Public Function) that, given a 1-column range, will return an array of its unique values. It has to do the same job that RemoveDuplicates method does but without changing anything, it should only return an array of unique values.

I wrote this code

```
Public varData() As Variant

Public Sub Suplem(rng As Range)

Dim tempSheet As Worksheet
Size = rng.Rows.Count
On Error GoTo tuda1
    Worksheets.Add.Name = "temp"
tuda1:
    Set tempSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("temp")
With tempSheet
    tempSheet.Range(tempSheet.Cells(1, 1), tempSheet.Cells(Size, 1)).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
    tempSheet.Range(tempSheet.Cells(1, 1), tempSheet.Cells(Size, 1)).RemoveDuplicates
    varData = tempSheet.Range(tempSheet.Cells(1, 1), tempSheet.Cells(Size, 1)).Value
End With
tempSheet.Delete

End Sub


Public Function UniqueVals(rng As Range)

ReDim varData(rng.Rows.Count - 1)
Call Suplem(rng)
Dim a() As Variant
UniqueVals = varData
Erase varData

End Function
```

UniqueVals function here calls Sub Suplem that creates temporary sheet, pastes into it a copy of initial range and removes duplicates from it. Then it records final range freed from duplicates to the global array varData. After that UniqueVals function returns data in varData and clears it.

The problem is that this function returns #VALUE! because of the temporary sheet which is created and modified within Sub. Any ideas on how to avoid this error? Can I use an array instead but in a range fashion, that is, by modifying it via formula?

Comment: If you have the dyanmic formulas, there is a `UNIQUE()` formula that does this. Dynamic Array formulas are available with Office 365 Subscription.

Comment: Or use a dictionary and utilize ```.exists()```

Comment: To avoid the error, you could just use the very last column on your existing sheet to perform the same operations. I assume your data set does not span 16,384 columns so there should be no issue. Once your code is complete, you can just clear the contents of this column before `End Sub`. Other solutions are ideal, this is just an FYI

Comment: @urdearboy but if this function is called from the worksheet, it will not work as a function called from the worksheet cannot make changes to other cells.

Comment: True - I have done this in the past. Must have not used UDFs

Answer (score 1):

If one does not have the Dynamic Array formula `UNIQUE()` then use this function that uses a dictionary.

```
Public Function UniqueVals(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim rngArray As Variant
    rngArray = Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange).Value

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim t As Variant
    For Each t In rngArray
        On Error Resume Next
            dict.Add t, t
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next t

    Dim temp() As Variant
    ReDim temp(1 To dict.Count, 1 To 1)

    Dim x As Long
    x = 1
    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In dict.Keys
        temp(x, 1) = key
        x = x + 1
    Next key

    UniqueVals = temp
End Function
```

Comment: What does creating the temp array at the end do compared to say just returning the dictionary keys array? Will a 1d array not work with worksheet functions etc?

Comment: @NickSlash it would be a horizontal array, The OP stated the array would be vertical.  I did it this way to avoid the `Application.Transpose` limit if the items are large or there are many.

Comment: @NickSlash and as I understand it, one cannot simply put the dictionary into cells without converting to array.

Comment: This method does, actually, work, although I'm not sure will it be fast when working with 10k+ rows of data or not. But the problem is that it can only be used for a range from exact same sheet, while if it is taken from a different sheet, an error occurs (#VALUE!)

Comment: @MarkRoyale see edit. It will not w work on different sheet. Also it should be very quick even with large ranges.